# Trying to dockerize a node.js file but keep getting error

Tags: node.js, docker, error-handling, dockerfile

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR ~/Desktop/CS612
COPY package.json ~/Desktop/CS612
RUN npm install
COPY . ~/Desktop/CS612
CMD node server.js
EXPOSE 3000
```

Okay I have switched it and was able to get this far:

```
Step 5/7 : COPY . ~/Desktop/CS612/
 ---> 885080c48872
Step 6/7 : CMD node server.js
 ---> Running in 7ffbaeec889f
 ---> 61654068c183
Removing intermediate container 7ffbaeec889f
Step 7/7 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 6862095ac871
 ---> abb84902c53b
Removing intermediate container 6862095ac871
Successfully built abb84902c53b
Successfully tagged restaurants:latest
Danas-MacBook-Air:CS612 DanaCarlin$ docker run restaurants
module.js:538
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module '/~/Desktop/CS612/server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Why am I getting this error now? It makes no sense, that is definitely  a file that holds the requests and responses

Comment: Please post your docker file. Also, check the error line.

Comment: Maybe the repository, you are copying files to, does not exist

Comment: Notice that in line 2 you have capital D and in line 3 lowercase (and line 5). Perhaps that is your issue? I'm not sure if it is case sensitive or not in the COPY command. And is restaurants a local existing image?

Comment: Also CS612 is different case on different lines.

Comment: To elaborate on what @MikeCheel said, `~/Desktop/CS612` is a completely different directory than `~/desktop/cs612`

Comment: `COPY . .` seems more right. `COPY package*.json ./` too.

Answer (score 0):

`WORKDIR ~/Desktop/CS612`

WORKDIR specifies the working directory inside the container, not the directory on Danas-MacBook-Air. The host working directory is closer to what Docker calls the build context on your MacBook air.

Also, **Docker needs absolute paths within the container**. You're creating a directory in the container `/~/Desktop/CS612`, which is where all the subsequent Dockerfile commands will run from as you finish the build. Probably not what you want.

tl;dr ditch the relative paths (`~/`) in the Dockerfile. Example: `COPY . /Desktop/CS612`.

edit: to reflect changes in the original question